# using drupal_process_states()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add dependencies to a set of fields, such that only one of the set can ever contain a value at any given time.

I see that [`drupal_process_states()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7) does pretty much what I want, but I'd have to define it separately for each element. It looks like I'd be using it with [`hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/7), since that takes `$elements` as an argument?

Is there anything that might simplify this? Specifically, is there a function that can apply rules per fieldset rather than per widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was confused about what `drupal_process_states()` does. It does not have to be declared like a hook or even invoked in my custom module. It is simply the machinery behind `#states` in the FormAPI. Simply using a `hook_form_alter()` and adding a `#states` array to the relevant fields is enough.